# how to convert nested payload into Java-JSONObject (net.minidev.json.JSONObject) for Restassured POST call

Tags: json, rest-assured

How to convert below nested payload into Java-JSONObject (net.minidev.json.JSONObject) for Restassured POST call request body ?

```
 {
  "object": "new_subway_group",
  "name": "Group 1",
  "subways": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup request body, use array or List for `[1,2,3]`

```java
JSONObject surveyPriceObject = new JSONObject();
surveyPriceObject.put("object", "new_subway_group");
surveyPriceObject.put("name", "Group 1");
surveyPriceObject.put("subways", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

---

Convert response to JSONObject

If the response has type `Response` then

```java
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
...
JSONObject object = res.jsonPath().getObject("", JSONObject.class);
System.out.println(object);
```

If the response has type `String` then

```java
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
...
JSONObject object = JsonPath.from(res).getObject("", JSONObject.class);
System.out.println(object);
```

Comment: This is for Request body. I need to send above JSON payload inside request body. Previously I've used JSONObject surveyPriceObject = new JSONObject(); but how to use it for [1,2,3] construct?

Comment: @user2451016 I've updated my code. Sorry for misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have now accepted your answer as working solution.